# Can a Summon spell power a Reserve feat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, summoning

The reserve feat Fiery Burst says:

> As long as you have a fire spell of 2nd level or higher available to cast, you can spend a standard action to...

The Summon Monster I spell (and, by extension, all summon monster spells) say:

> When you use a summoning spell to summon an air, chaotic, earth, evil, fire, good, lawful, or water creature, it is a spell of that type.

If I have Summon Monster V prepared, I technically could use it to summon 1d4+1 small fire elementals (off the Summon Monster III list).  Does this mean I have a fifth-level fire spell "available to cast", and thus I can use the fiery burst feat with a spell level of 5?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it doesn't really matter if the spell with the [Fire] descriptor comes from Evocation or Conjuration school, I'm afraid that Summon Monster can't be used to power Fiery Burst:

> Only actual spells or spell slots allow the character to use the
>   primary benefit of a reserve feat. Spell-like abilities, supernatural
>   abilities, and extraordinary abilities—even if they mimic or duplicate
>   an appropriate spell—do not qualify. *Spells that do not have a
>   descriptor until cast (**such as the summon monster spells**) can't be
>   used to gain the primary benefit of a reserve feat.*

If you had a summoning spell that can summon ONLY fire-typed creatures (and had the [Fire] descriptor right from the box), it would work, **but Summon Monster V won't**.